# How to auto-yes "drush features-revert-all" ... via terminus

Tags: drush, features

On a local machine

```
drush features-revert-all
```

will convert all features to codebase definition.
On a local machine ...

```
drush -y
```

will auto-yes any command.
On a local machine

```
terminus -y command
```

will auto-yes as well.

But when combined, even

```
terminus -y drush -y yoursite.dev -y features-revert-all -y
```

... will still ask for a key-press.

How can it be forced to run non-interactively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `--` separator to your command. The options for Terminus come before this marker, and the options for Drush come after.

In other words:

```
terminus -y drush site.dev -- features-revert-all -y
```

**Explanation:**

In programs that support it, `--` means "all of the options that come after should be treated as arguements". The command `terminus drush` passes all of its arguments through to Drush.

Comment: This works for me. Awesome!